# Update not installing!

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4 isn't installing the new update! Do you have to have service to update? It keeps saying update failed because I'm not connected to the Internet, but I am! Help help!

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging your device into your computer and downloading it from iTunes. If you get any error messages, please paste them here.